# Reducing EMI emission from 20KHz PWM

Tags: pwm, filter, dc-motor, emi-filtering

I have a small 1.5A @ 12V (~10 Amp stall current @ 12Vdc) DC Brushed motor connected to a H-Bridge switched with 20KHz PWM.

The motor is connected to the bridge through a 3 meters long cable:
[H BRIDGE]--PCB-TRACK--[CONNECTOR]=====(3 METERS CABLE)====[DC-MOTOR]

My concern is that the cable will emit EMI.
At 20KHz switching 1.5A through 3mts long cable, is this a valid concern?

Should I use some inductor between the bridge and the connector to the cable to damp high frequency? Or LC low pass filter?

I don't know how to calculate the loss insertion needed for the filter.
Ideally I want the loss to be infinite above the cutoff frequency, but considering the practical implementation, should I just go with as more loss abbove 20Khz, as better it is?

Comment: Add schematic. Measure the EMI.

Comment: Usually from a such device with PWM output goes a twisted pair with shield connected to earth.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You've encountered a very complex and often annoying feature of electronics: electromagnetic compliance. There are system, design, and standards components to consider. Without spending a lot of money to test your system, your concerns are mostly including some reasonable mitigation and not causing any noticeable interference. If you're making a product, you'll need that testing, though.

Comment: I am designing a product. There are no regulations (yet) for this particular product, but it is used in an environment where we have many audio AM/FM radios. I had some problems before where the squelch was triggering because of SMPS noise. I solved with 100nF caps and ferrite beads. For this motor, I just want to have a starting point. If it fails in the test I can supress more... but I want to start with something that gives me a good chance  in passsing the test.

Comment: Have your Trise and Tfall edges be faster than 500 nanoseconds. That will keep your EMI out of the AM band. Now your task is filtering out *all* energy that might target FM band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20kHz is slow.

Use gate resistors to adjust the MOSFET switching time to keep switching losses reasonable, but not faster.

With 20kHz (ie, 50µs period) you can switch in 500ns. No need to switch in 10ns, that will only generate an enormous amount of EMI.

If you only switch one side of the H-bridge your cable will radiate common mode noise. This can be mitigated by switching both sides in opposing polarities all the time and/or applying a ferrite core on your cable.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by switching both sides in opposite polarities? Wouldn't that create either shoot-through or a braking effect?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an LC filter because this is going to distort your square wave and a motor is an RL circuit. The alternative is that you can use a shield cable to avoid emitting EMI. The shield of the cable has to be connected to the shield of the PCB.